# Rails what is the best gem to scrape websites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping

What is the best gem to (screen) scrape websites that is password protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look here: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing.html and http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients.html.

I think that for password you can use mechanize

You have a lot of options there.

Look at this question for an example: [Ruby Mechanize login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663967/ruby-mechanize-login-not-working)

Comment: I am using it, but are always running into problems. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Mechanize is very well tested and quite robust. Odds are good if you're having problems its due to something you're doing in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) gem. It allows you to fill forms, store cookies, and select content using css selectors.

([Railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize))

Comment: Better docs (same content, better presentation) available at http://rubydoc.info/github/tenderlove/mechanize/